# How do I disable gzip compression for flv files in IIS 7 with runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests set to true?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, web-config, gzip

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 Website that is running on IIS 7 and I would like to have my static content (like css files, javascript files, etc) gzip compressed as well as my dynamic content (.net pages). The problem is that I need to make sure flv files (flash video files) are not gzip compressed because that causes problems with the flash video player I'm using, [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/).

I've added the following line to my web.config which enables compression, but then my flv files are also being gzip compressed:

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
```

I've tried to add the following to my web.config, but it did not change anything:

```
<httpCompression>
    <staticTypes>
        <remove mimeType="video/x-flv"/>
    </staticTypes>
    <dynamicTypes>
        <remove mimeType="video/x-flv"/>
    </dynamicTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

I have to turn off doDynamicCompression for the flv files not to be gzip compressed. I think that it is treating flv files as dynamic content because I have runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" in my web.config (which I need for some of the things I'm doing with routing).

In summary, how do I disable gzip compression for flv files?

Comment: This is I believe what you want

`<add mimeType="video/x-flv" enabled="false" />`



Note that I also think it can only be done at the ApplicationHost.config level in IIS7.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best thing to do is to manually manage what is getting gzip'd.  Sometimes what is gzip'd can actually increase in size, like a swf, which is what I just ran into. Previously my `application.config` had this block in it, and after I removed the shockwave mime type swf's stopped compressing

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
        <dynamicTypes>
                <clear />
                <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/x-amf" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/x-shockwave-flash" enabled="true" /> <!-- notice the swf mime type -->
                <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </dynamicTypes>
        <staticTypes>
                <clear />
                <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/x-shockwave-flash" enabled="true" /> <!-- notice the swf mime type -->
                <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

This is in my application config in `windows\system32\intersrv\config\application.config` but I am pretty sure you can do this per website in your web.config under `system.webserver`.

All I had to do for me was to remove the shockwave mime type and it stopped getting compressed but all other valid mime types were.