# Accessing .FLV movies on a virtual directory in IIS 7.5 using FlowPlayer

Tags: flash, flv, flowplayer

I have a website setup in IIS 7.5 with a virtual directory pointing to a local folder outside of the www root of my website e.g:

```
the website is c:\website

the virtual directory is in c:\images
```

I use [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) to play my movies, when I put the movie path in my website root directory structure, say c:\website\movies\a.flv it works fine in the player, but if I put them inside the virtual directory and point the player to play it from there using a relative URL, it doesn't work

I suspect that this has to do with either permissions or flash configurations to allow it to access directories outside of the scope of the website, but I have no idea where to edit such settings

Thank you

Comment: I know this is an old question...I noticed this behavior when content compression was enabled. I'm guessing the player can't deal with a gzipped stream.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669833/how-do-i-disable-gzip-compression-for-flv-files-in-iis-7-with-runallmanagedmodul

Answer (score 0):

When you create the virtual directory it gives you the opportunity to set the 'Pass-through authentication' by clicking 'Connect as...' and specifying either an exact user OR to use the 'Application user (pass-through authentication)' which means to use the user that the website itself runs under.

If you are looking to use the same security context your website runs under, go to your website and hit 'Basic Settings' from the top-right area of the IIS Manager console. You'll see the 'Application pool:' your site is running under.

Next, cancel out of that dialog and go to 'Application Pools' on the top left. Click on the application pool your site is using then go to 'Advanced Settings'. Under here you can see 'Identity' under the 'Process Model' section. This is the user that your website runs under. The only exception to this is if you have some kind of 'impersonation' happening on your website, which isn't likely if you've asked the above question. (As it suggests/requires a deeper understanding of this topic. In which case, you'd probably know this already. No offense, haha.)

Once you know what user we are talking about, you can simply go to Windows Explorer and set permissions to the real physical folder that your virtual directory points to.